# How to set typeface for the text view xml layout

Tags: android, textview, typeface, xml-layout

I have created an XML layout with the name `def_list`. I have assigned an id for it and that is `def_list_textview`. I have put a font called `bn.ttf` in the assets folder.

The XML layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/def_list_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right" >
    </TextView>
```

But when I set a typeface for it using the code:

```
def_list_tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.def_list_textview);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/bn.ttf");
def_list_tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

I get a nullPointerException in the LogCat. I don't know why.

This is my LogCat:

```
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.adeveloper.handydic/net.adeveloper.dic.PortDef}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254):     at net.adeveloper.dic.PortDef.onCreate(PortDef.java:53)
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254):     at     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-26 17:14:56.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1254):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post your LogCat please

Comment: At where you got NPE? Post your stackTrace. Post your code. And also tell at which line you got NPE? Post 53 line

Comment: tell me which is the line 53 in portdef class

Comment: Before adding those code, my app was working well. I commented first two lines and it worked. But when I add the third code: def_list_tv.setTypeface(tf); it got error.

Comment: The line 53 is the third line of code I posted: def_list_tv.setTypeface(tf);

Answer (score 3):

Problem might be in

```
this.getAssets()
```

getAssets() is method from Context so try to pass context object instead of **this**

Try

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/bn.ttf");
```

or

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/bn.ttf");
```

Here mContext is object of Context

Edit :

Please check if following Custom TextView can help you

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView{
  public CustomTextView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs,int defStyle){
    super(context,attrs,defStyle);
    init();
  }
  public CustomTextView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context,attrs);
    init();
  }
  public CustomTextView(Context context){
    super(context);
    init();
  }

  private void init(){
    if(!isInEditMode()){
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/bn.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }
  }
}
```

I have used this class in one of my previous project

Comment: I have another similar code for another text view that is in a different XML file and by setting that typeface it works well. but for this whole XML layout as a text view it just doesn't work. Don't you think I can't reach XML Text-View id in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code, seems to be perfect
Check out, font name is same as you have written in asset folder -> fonts folder. If same then try out by moving your fonts directly to asset folder and here just setting "bn.ttf" instead of  "fonts/bn.ttf".

Comment: I think it's for the XML layout. For text views that are not just the whole XML it works. but for this, it can't. Am I right?

Comment: @AliAllahyar: put your textview in linear layout or relative layout and then try out.. it will surely work.. i have tried out. I think issue is in your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

remove your typeface file from fonts/ and put it directly inside of Assets folder, should works!
hope to help

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. As silwar pointed it was for the context for I hadn't assigned an activity with the content view of my XML layout. I was just using another activity which had a different content view.

But there is one question. Still the text view doesn't seem to apply the noted font. It just uses a default font. I have the noted XML layout for a list view which I want to use the typeface I have assigned. It adds the strings to an ArrayList and It the adapter for the list view uses the code as follows:

```
defListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.def_list, list);
defListView.setAdapter(defListAdapter);
```

def_list is the XML layout which I pointed out in my previous question. defListView is the list view. Why don't I see the desired typeface?

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention to `"fonts/bn.ttf"`. All the words must be in prototype.
May the `bn.ttf` be `BN.TTF`. So pay attention to `assets` folder and make sure from prototype name.

Answer (score 0):

Try Creating a CustomTextView like the one below:

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/arial.ttf");
        setTypeface(typeFace,Typeface.NORMAL);
    }
}
```

}

And please your fonts file in **assets/fonts/arial.ttf** make sure that the name of the font must be same in the CustomTextView java file and to call the CustomTextView from **xml** you can use the following code:

```
<com.package.name.CustomTextView
//fill in the details
/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def_list_tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.def_list_textview);   //line no 1
System.out.println("Textview==="+def_list_tv);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/bn.ttf");
def_list_tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

If you see **Textview===null** in your Logcat,specify the correct textview id in line no 1.I got the same error which u got when did this mistake.I hope this will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this... and I think some thing wrong in your path check the path

```
def_list_tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.def_list_textview);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "bn.ttf");
def_list_tv.setTypeface(tf,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TextViewPlus extends TextView {
    private static final String TAG = "TextView";

    public TextViewPlus(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextViewPlus);
        String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.TextViewPlus_customFont);
        setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
        Typeface tf = null;
        try {
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), asset);  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: "+e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        setTypeface(tf);  
        return true;
    }
}
```